# Broken podcast link

Tags: bug, status-completed

I was trying to find the podcast for Jeff Atwood's [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/313241) and I ran into [a broken link](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/audio/stackoverflow-podcast-005.mp3). I was redirected here to report it so euhm... reported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats podcast #5, probably one of the best ones!

Here's a link to it, I'll also edit the post you posted!

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/05/podcast-5/

I also fixed the original post located at meta.stackexchange:

[The Many Memes of Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514)

Comment: Thanks but don't edit it, then the broken link is gone :)

Comment: We want it to be gone otherwise others will make another meta post about it just like you did.  That is the point of stackoverflow/se sites.  Posts that are broken if they have value should be fixed!

Comment: Oh you mean **the** post, I thought you meant my post here

Comment: No why would I edit your post?  I'm just going to fix the original thread over at meta.stackexchange such that the link works from now on.  This is to avoid anyone else posting this same question in the future.

Comment: Didn't know you work for stack exchange ;)

Comment: I don't work for stackexchange.

Comment: Oh it's the post about the memes, not the podcast site. Guess I should go to sleep soon...